# Where is the build for wso2 1.10.1?

Tags: wso2, jwt, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to upgrade a wso2 install from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0 to support HTTP PATCH, however, the bug here: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4504 has broken JWT generation. I see the bug is fixed in 1.10.1, but I cannot find any reference to this version in documentation or in the release downloads for wso2.

Is this version released? Is it available, or does it have to be build manually? If so, could you provide instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any release with 1.10.1 version, next released version is API Manager 2.0.

You can find the components here: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.0.4

Produce distribution here: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v2.0.0